# How do you check if a string does not have a specific symbol when using "any_of"?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I am trying to check a string to see if it meets all the requirements and one of those requirements is that does not have either `'*'` or `'%'`. Using `std::any_of` to check the entire string and got it working with `isupper` and `islower` but can't figure it out for those 2 characters.

Sample of what I have so far, the 3rd if statement is as far as I got.

```
if(std::any_of(nPass.cbegin(), nPass.cend(), ::isupper))
{
   if(std::any_of(nPass.cbegin(), nPass.cend(), ::islower) ) 
   {
      if(std::any_of(nPass.cbegin(), nPass.cend(), ::!='*'))
      {
           return true; // returns true if all criteria is met
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with lambda functions?  Also, `std::isalpha` is the function you want to use, not separate calls to `isupper` and `islower`.

Comment: I think is more readable using `&&` for conditions that making anidated `if`'s

Comment: So what exactly is the criteria?  It is confusing as to what a good string is supposed to be.  Is it all alphabetical and any special characters **except** the two characters you specified?  I think you didn't translate the criteria you want into proper logic.

Comment: Your problem seems like checking that password is hard to remember but easy to crack: https://xkcd.com/936/

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use the algorithm std::any_of for the third check. You can use the method `find_first_of` of the class `std::string`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

bool check( const std::string &s )
{
    return std::any_of( std::begin( s ), std::end( s ), ::isupper ) &&
           std::any_of( std::begin( s ), std::end( s ), ::islower ) &&
           s.find_first_of( "*% " ) == std::string::npos;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << check( "A" ) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << check( "a" ) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << check( "Aa%" ) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << check( "Aa*%" ) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << check( "Aa" ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
false
false
false
false
true
```

I suppose that the string has to contain both upper case and lower case letters. If you are checking just alpha characters then you could use `::isalpha`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! But I can't find a good explanation for what `std::string::npos` is or why adding that on at the end works. Also the requirement for this was just if those 2 special characters are present in the "password" it isn't valid, not for all special characters to be left out.

Comment: @Raymond The member function returns the position of the found symbol. If the symbol is not found the function returns the value std::string::npos that is equal to std::string::size_type( -1 ).